# How can I use use cpdclt dsjob for DaaS (DataStage as a Service)?

Tags: datastage, cloud-pak-for-data

I would like to execute "cpdctl dsjob" explained in the document below URL.

https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/dstage/dsnav/topics/cli.html

I download cpdctl from below URL but can not use dsjob option.

https://github.com/IBM/cpdctl/releases/

Is there additional procedure for using dsjob option?

I setup configration and run "cpdctl job run" but "cpdctrl dsjob" option is not appear.

```
# ./cpdctl dsjob
Error: unknown command "dsjob" for "cpdctl"

Did you mean this?
        job

Run 'cpdctl --help' for usage.
unknown command "dsjob" for "cpdctl"
```

Did you mean this?
job

Answer (score 1):

I found that CPDCTL_ENABLE_DSJOB environment is required to use dsjob option.

export  CPDCTL_ENABLE_DSJOB=1

```
# ./cpdctl dsjob Error: unknown command "dsjob" for "cpdctl"

Did you mean this?
        job

Run 'cpdctl --help' for usage.
unknown command "dsjob" for "cpdctl"

Did you mean this?
        job

# export  CPDCTL_ENABLE_DSJOB=1
#  ./cpdctl dsjob
The IBM DataStage service provides APIs to manage jobs, this command provides some of legacy dsjob commandline functionality.

Usage:
  cpdctl dsjob [command]

Available Commands:
  lprojects     List Projects.
  ljobs         List Jobs.
  run           Manage Job Runs.
  logdetail     Print DataStage job run logs.
  logsum        Print Summary of Datastage job run logs.
  lognewest     Returns newest event id from DataStage job run logs.
  jobinfo       List Job Information.
  migrate       Migrate a exported legacy isx file into nextgen Datastage project.
  lflows        List DataStage flows.
  compile       Compile DataStage flows.
  lenvs         List Environments.
  lhws          List Hardware Specifications.
  env-create    Create Environment.
  hwspec-create Create Hardware Specification.

Flags:
  -h, --help   help for dsjob

Global Flags:
      --context string
      --cpdconfig string
      --output-path string
      --raw-output

Use "cpdctl dsjob [command] --help" for more information about a command.
#
```